# Difference between transition: scale VS transition: transform VS transition: all

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am applying multiple transform functions - scale() and translate() - in CSS and want to apply transition to only **scale** property, so I tried the following code block below:

```
input:focus + label, input:not(:placeholder-shown)  + label {
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(3px, -6px);
  transition: scale 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

However, this didn't had any effect.. I was able to achieve the desired effect I wanted when I tried the following instead

```
input:focus + label, input:not(:placeholder-shown)  + label {
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(3px, -6px);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

which I don't get because doesn't `transition: transform 0.2s ease-in` select all properties - both scale and translate?

When I tried `transition: all 0.2s ease-in`, this had a different effect from `transition: transform 0.2s ease-in` when I anticipated it to be the same.

In short, could someone help me understand the difference between
`transition: **scale** 0.2s ease-in` VS `transition: **transform** 0.2s ease-in` VS `transition: **all** 0.2s ease-in`?

Greatly appreciate your time and energy in answering

Comment: [*The `scale` CSS property allows you to specify scale transforms individually and independently of the `transform` property.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale) They are two different properties.

Answer (score 0):

The word given inside transition defines the property that will change with the transition.

`scale` is not a property (it is the value of `transform`), so nothing happen

`transform` is a property, so all modifications defined into it will be applied (`scale` and `translate`)

`all` means that the transition will be applied to all changed properties.

I am not sure that the "property" word is exact but I guess you've got what I am speaking about.

Comment: Makes sense. What can I do if I want to apply the the transition to only scale?

Comment: You can one class for the scale and another one for the translate, per example.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "one class".

Comment: When you create your element, you can add classes : `<a class="link login-link">Log in</a>`, per example, will add two classes, one named "link", the seconde named "login-link". You can then use stylesheet rules like this : `.link { color: red } .login-link { background: blue }` if you wants all links in red and all login links with a blue background. In your example, you can use one of theses classes to apply the translate (no transition), and another one to apply the scale (transition), adding the transition only to the last one. (I would say "add one class" and forgot the "add", sorry)

Comment: As said @HaoWu above, you can also use the `scale`property, which seem more adapted and simpler than my solution instead.